# Recommendations for microservice code / modules

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, microservices

I am new to microservices and am learning Spring Boot
I have IntelliJ Ultimate and am wondering how best to structure my microservice code

For the system that i am building that will have a few microservices should I..

1. Open 1 IntelliJ containing a module for each Spring Boot microservice
2. Open multiple instances of IntelliJ and have one Spring Boot microservice per instance of IntelliJ

I think it will be tricky to do 2 if I have a lot of microservices but I do not know if IntelliJ is able to have multiple Spring Boot microservices running at the same time in one instance of IntelliJ

Any advice on how you work with microservice code / projects would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify when I say module I mean IntelliJ modules and not Spring Boot modules

Comment: I will recommend using spring STS for spring-boot microservices. Here one sample project https://github.com/atulquest93/microservice-circuit-breaker-with-hystrix with 2 micro-services and other spring cloud dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InteliJ is able to have a lot of Spring Boot microserices/application running at the same time. It have no impact on performance, even if you run all microvervices in debug mode. I would choose first option. This is an approach, we are using in our poject:

Start new project in IntelliJ. 
For each microservice create new module in InteliJ.

Benefits:

- If someone new want to work on that project, he can import one
  project and have all microservices imported at once. Even if he would
  work only in few of them, he can look how others are build.
- in InteliJ you can create Run Configuration as "Compaund". So, when you want to run all your services at once, you can do it with just one click.

But, if you have 1500 employees, want go full netflix way and create 500 microservices, then better way will be to keep them separate :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of microservices is organisational scalability. You have several teams working on different microservices at the same time. Also, it should be possible to develop, build and run each microservice on its own. If you don't have those goals, you get all the complexities of microservices and very little of the advantages.

In such a scenario, each microservice should live in its own version control. As long as this is given, if the IDE supports multiple version control sources per module, go for 2). Otherwise I guess you must stick with 1).